# Grails Unit Testing Extends

Tags: unit-testing, grails

**You can find a sample app that recreates the problem on [github](https://github.com/sircelsiussexy/grails-unit-test-inheritance)**

I created an app with two domains: `Abstract` and `Extends`. As their names state, the first one is `abstract`, and the second one `extends` the first one.

I am trying to test an `ExtendsController` method that calls `Abstract.list()`. In my test class, I have created three instances of `Extends` names `extends1`, `extends2` and `extends3`.

I would expect my method to return `[extend1, extend2, extend3]`, so I'm testing it with

```
assert controller.list() == `[extend1, extend2, extend3]
```

However, the test fails with the following output:

```
assert controller.list() == [extend1, extend2, extend3]
       |          |      |   |        |        |
       |          |      |   |        |        com.test.Extend : 3
       |          |      |   |        com.test.Extend : 2
       |          |      |   com.test.Extend : 1
       |          |      false
       |          [com.test.Extend : 1, com.test.Extend : 2, com.test.Extend : 3]
       com.test.ExtendController@61d66115
```

**Why does it fail? How do I fix it?**

I'm using grails 2.2.4

### Edit

I'm aware that this will create a database table for my `Abstract` class, that is the behavior I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to overwrite `equals` method in `Extend` class. Otherwise, the comparison will return false, because technically the objects are different.